# foreach with iteration and -replace using PowerShell

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, powershell-3.0

I have a text file with filenames in it. There are multiple duplicate names so every filename with a duplicate I have to concatenate a sequential number after each duplicate file name. For example:

Initially the text file looks like this:

```
filenamex
filenamex
filenamex
otherfilename
otherfilename
otherfilename
otherfilename
```

The actions I need for the code to do is this:

- first `filenamex` stays the same
- second `filenamex` replaced with `filenamex1`
- third `filenamex` replaced with `filenamex2`
- first `otherfilename` stays the same
- second `otherfilename` replaced with `otherfilename1`
- third `otherfilename` replaced with `otherfilename2`
- fourth `otherfilename` replaced with `otherfilename3`

Eventually the text file will look like this:

```
filenamex
filenamex1
filenamex2
otherfilename
otherfilename1
otherfilename2
otherfilename3
```

Here is my code, but I'm getting all kinds of piping errors. I am trying to use `-replace`, iteration, and `Get-Content` with `foreach`. However, I'm having difficulty making it all come together and work.

```
$inputFile1 = Get-Content H:\test\outputfile.txt

for ($i=0; $i -lt $inputFile1.Count; $i++) {
    $k=1
    $j=$i

    while ($inputFile1[$i] = $inputFile1[$j+1]) {
        (Get-Content H:\test\outputfile.txt).Replace($inputFile1[$i+1], $inputFile1[$i + 1] + $k.ToString() + ".pdf") |
            Out-File H:\test\outputfile2.txt -Append

        $k++
        $j++
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the errors you're getting. Contrary to popular belief error message don't exist to annoy the user, but for providing vital troubleshooting information.

Comment: there are no error messages but the output adds on the duplicates like this:
filename1
filename1
filename1
...and keeps going.

Comment: Also I took off the "append" switch for the heck of it. As I suspected it just keeps adding numbers higher and higher indefinitely like this: filename1, filename2, filename3........filename100. I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place. If I append it, it won't change the original values.